# VC Admin + Azure Web Apps + Hangfire Job + Worker Process requested recycle due to 'Percent Memory' limit

Tags: azure, web-applications, virtocommerce

When we start re-index catalog (~15000 products) in VC Admin, we can not finish the process because Azure automatically recycles Web Apps.

Error message:
Worker Process requested recycle due to 'Percent Memory' limit. Memory Used: 4273229824 out of 3757625344 available. Exceeded 90 Percent of Memory.

Web Apps Price plan is S2.

Please advise.

PS: Temporary workaround is "Increase price plan to S3".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is cause because "Smart-cache" didn't use cache expiration.

How to solve this problem:

- Update [VirtoCommerce.Cache module](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-module-cache/releases/tag/v1.0.8) to latest version.
- Add follow section to platform **Web.config**

  ```
   <system.runtime.caching>
      <memoryCache>
             <namedCaches>
                  <add name="memCacheHandle"  physicalMemoryLimitPercentage="80" pollingInterval="00:00:30" />
      </namedCaches>
  </memoryCache>
  ```

Comment: Where to find **Web.config** in function app ?

Comment: My function app is also having the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757891/azure-function-app-stops-automatically-with-orange-exclamatory-mark